# Change a value in a column in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to update a value in a column from a certain table. I tried this :

```
 public void updateOneColumn(String TABLE_NAME, String Column, String rowId, String ColumnName, String newValue){
                 String sql = "UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME +" SET " + ColumnName+ " = "+newValue+" WHERE "+Column+ " = "+rowId;
                 db.beginTransaction();
                 SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
                 try{
                     stmt.execute();
                     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                 }finally{
                     db.endTransaction();
                 }

        }
```

and I call this method like this :

```
 db.updateOneColumn("roadmap", "id_roadmap",id,"sys_roadmap_status_mobile_id", "1");
```

which means that I want to set the value `1` in the column `sys_roadmap_status_mobile_id` when `id_roadmap = id.`

The problem is that nothing happens. Where is my mistake?

Comment: First of all, please read up on SQL injection attacks!

Comment: And, what data type are your columns? If they're character types, you'll probably want to quote your strings. You also haven't provided what value `id` contains or any sample data...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Easy solution:

```
String sql = "UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME +" SET " + ColumnName+ " = '"+newValue+"' WHERE "+Column+ " = "+rowId;
```

Better solution:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(ColumnName, newValue);
db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, Column + "= ?", new String[] {rowId});
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, but the value is not set in table.

Comment: @Gabrielle see if its really affecting any row. check the number of rows affected

Comment: I have the same rows as before calling update. Nothing is affect. All the columns are String.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I get the database from data/data/ and open it.

Comment: What values does the above update method return when it runs?

Comment: I put your solution in a method that return int. When I call this method, it return 1.

Comment: Why is it considerer better ?

Comment: @Jaydev because it takes care of escaping the values you insert

Answer (score 1):

The below solution works for me for updating single row values:

```java
public long fileHasBeenDownloaded(String fileName) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    long id = 0;

    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(IFD_ISDOWNLOADED, 1);

        // The columns for the WHERE clause
        String selection = (IFD_FILENAME + " = ?");

        // The values for the WHERE clause
        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(InhalerFileDownload.fileName)};

        id = db.update(TABLE_INHALER_FILE_DOWNLOAD, cv, selection, selectionArgs);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return id;
}
```